# pandas sort column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

ie)

```
        count
2015-01  2
2015-02  1
2015-03  4
```

for the group i tried pd.groupby(b,by=[b.index.month,b.index.year])

but there was object has no attribute 'month' error

Comment: Are those actual date objects or strings?

Comment: date is coloumn  in dataframe objects

Answer (score 1):

Apply `sorted` with the `key` parameter set to `pd.to_datetime`

```
df.assign(date=df.date.apply(sorted, key=pd.to_datetime))

  id                                  date
0  a              [2015-02-01, 2015-03-01]
1  b                          [2015-03-01]
2  s              [2015-01-01, 2015-03-01]
3  f  [2015-01-01, 2015-01-01, 2015-03-01]
```

Then use `pd.value_counts`

```
pd.value_counts(pd.to_datetime(df.date.sum()).strftime('%Y-%m'))

2015-03    4
2015-01    3
2015-02    1
dtype: int64
```

---

***debugging***

You should be able to copy and paste this code... please verify that it runs as expected.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        id=list('absf'),
        date=[
            ['2015-03-01', '2015-02-01'],
            ['2015-03-01'],
            ['2015-01-01', '2015-03-01'],
            ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2015-03-01']
        ]
    ))[['id', 'date']]

print(df.assign(date=df.date.apply(sorted, key=pd.to_datetime)))
print()
print(pd.value_counts(pd.to_datetime(df.date.sum()).strftime('%Y-%m')))
```

You should expect to see

```
  id                                  date
0  a              [2015-02-01, 2015-03-01]
1  b                          [2015-03-01]
2  s              [2015-01-01, 2015-03-01]
3  f  [2015-01-01, 2015-01-01, 2015-03-01]

2015-03    4
2015-01    3
2015-02    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is?  You showed a dataframe `df`.  Did you run this code on `df`?  You also did not give enough information to tell what is going on.

Comment: @d.doo see the debugging section of my updated answer.

Comment: df.assign(dt=df.dt.apply(sorted, key=pd.to_datetime))  there was TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'> and ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full stack trace?

Comment: Debugging code works ok for me pd.__version__ 0.19.2 - d.doo could you just confirm if the debugging code works correctly please. The problem may be with your source data. pd.to_datetime also has errors='coerce' and errors='ignore' that you could try.